# How to align a character vertically in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I am wanting to align a single character in an Android TextView to the top, similar to a superscript but such that the superscripted character's top matches the rest of the characters' tops.

[image]

For the sake of simplicity, I have tried accomplishing this with Spannable, however, nothing is standing out that can work. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: I should make it more clear that **I want all of the characters' tops to align**. Regular superscripts do not function this way.

Comment: Have you tried generating a `Spannable` from HTML? `<sub>` and `<sup>` are supported: http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: Spannable superscripts are also possible with SuperscriptSpan. A superscript is not _quite_ the effect I want. Please see my EDIT.

I would also prefer to avoid HTML.fromHTML as the parser's behavior can be less predictable than native implementations with Spannables. HTML.fromHTML, after all, is just providing a Spanned with a lot of parsing overhead.

Comment: @Anthony please check my answer edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with superscript is it places the bottom of the text at approximately the middle of the font. It does not align the tops or change the font to a smaller size, as my image example.

The solution I have arrived to extends the SuperscriptSpan. This will shift the baseline and scale down the font size. Note that it includes a constructor to set the shiftPercentage. This a percentage which accounts for the error between ascent value and the height of the characters being used (numbers in my case.) For the default android font, 0.25 appeared to be an appropriate value.

```
    class TopAlignSuperscriptSpan extends SuperscriptSpan {
        //divide superscript by this number
        protected int fontScale = 2;

        //shift value, 0 to 1.0
        protected float shiftPercentage = 0;

        //doesn't shift
        TopAlignSuperscriptSpan() {}

        //sets the shift percentage
        TopAlignSuperscriptSpan( float shiftPercentage ) {
            if( shiftPercentage > 0.0 && shiftPercentage < 1.0 )
                this.shiftPercentage = shiftPercentage;
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState( TextPaint tp ) {
            //original ascent
            float ascent = tp.ascent();

            //scale down the font
            tp.setTextSize( tp.getTextSize() / fontScale );

            //get the new font ascent
            float newAscent = tp.getFontMetrics().ascent;

            //move baseline to top of old font, then move down size of new font
            //adjust for errors with shift percentage
            tp.baselineShift += ( ascent - ascent * shiftPercentage )
                    - (newAscent - newAscent * shiftPercentage );
        }

        @Override
        public void updateMeasureState( TextPaint tp ) {
            updateDrawState( tp );
        }
    }

    //let's apply it to a string
    str.setSpan( new TopAlignSuperscriptSpan( (float)0.25 ), start, end,
                 Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("123<sup>4</sup>"));
```

**EDIT**

Replace the `html` in the `fromHtml` method with one of [these](https://jsfiddle.net/77dpedcg/)